# authenticate users in angular through azure ad and authorize to blob storage

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, azure-ad-msal

I build an app in angular and i want to enable authenticated users the  ability to downlead files acording their access permissions for this I try to use Azure AD and azure rbac for authentication and autheriztion, and use azure blob in order to store my files ,I searched a lot on the internet, and although I came across solutions on how to authenticate by msal library  I did not find any solution on how to authenticate and AUTHERIZE users to use blob storage , I would very appreciate many  instructions or tutorial how to do solve this issue .
best regards ,
gal

Answer (score 1):

Is your code running in browser? Currently for browser `@azure/blob-storage` only supports [using SAS token](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/storage/storage-blob#with-sas-token)

`BlobServiceClient` constructor does [take a `TokenCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobserviceclient?view=azure-node-latest#BlobServiceClient_string__StorageSharedKeyCredential___AnonymousCredential___TokenCredential__StoragePipelineOptions_), which is an interface you could implement:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/core-auth/tokencredential?view=azure-node-latest

The SDK library will use the provided token as a Bearer token when sending requests to Azure Blob Service.  I haven't tried this with RBAC though.

Hope in the future the SDK will have better integration with AAD/RBAC for browsers.

Comment: As far as I know you can be authenticated in blob in front of the ad.
I found this example that does this in .dnot: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet
 and another example that does this in react,https://dev.to/425show/connecting-to-azure-blob-storage-from-react-using-azure-identity-16l0
 but I did not find an explanation how to do it in angular. 
i quite lost and I would love to get any help on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the token for blob storage using :-

```
this.authService
      .acquireTokenSilent({
        scopes: ['https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation'],
      })
      .then((tokenResponse) => {tokenResponse.accessToken})
```

Then wrap the token something like this :-

```
TestTokenCredential(tokenResponse.accessToken) {
    return {
      getToken: function (_scope, _opts) {
        return {
          token: tokenResponse.accessToken,
          expiresOnTimestamp: Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000,
        };
      },
    };
  }
```

And ultimately use the token return by the above function to get the blob container client like :-

```
  private containerClient(token: any): ContainerClient {
    return new BlobServiceClient(
      `https://${this.picturesAccount}.blob.core.windows.net`,
      token
    ).getContainerClient(this.picturesContainer);
  }
```